# PL/SQL error ORA-06550 & PLS-00103 in an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure BEFOR_VIP_RESET.CP_UPDATE_DTL_YHJ_SUM
is
cursor cur IS SELECT TRIM(DC.INV_NUM) INV_NUM,
                     SUM(DC.REDEEMVALUE) SUM_REDEEMVALUES 
              FROM DINV_COUPON DC 
              GROUP BY DC.INV_NUM;   
INT_COUNT_DINV_COUPON_BY_INV number;
begin
    for RUR1 in cur LOOP
        BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO INT_COUNT_DINV_COUPON_BY_INV 
            FROM DINV_DTL_YHJ DDY 
            WHERE TRIM(DDY.INV_NUM) = TRIM(RUR1.INV_NUM);

            IF (INT_COUNT_DINV_COUPON_BY_INV != 0) 
            THEN
                UPDATE DINV_DTL_YHJ D_D_Y 
                SET D_D_Y.REDEEMWAY = (RUR1.SUM_REDEEMVALUES/INT_COUNT_DINV_COUPON_BY_INV); --this error
            END IF;
        END;
    END LOOP;
end CP_UPDATE_DTL_YHJ_SUM;
```

Error message:

```
ORA-06550: line 12, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
. ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
```

1. When I debug I find `INT_COUNT_DINV_COUPON_BY_INV` and `RUR1.INV_NUM` have the right value.
2. When I change:

   ```
   UPDATE DINV_DTL_YHJ D_D_Y 
   SET D_D_Y.REDEEMWAY = (RUR1.SUM_REDEEMVALUES/INT_COUNT_DINV_COUPON_BY_INV);
   ```

to

```
    UPDATE DINV_DTL_YHJ D_D_Y 
    SET D_D_Y.REDEEMWAY = 66;
```

I also have the same error message.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please describe the issue that you're having, and what you've tried to do to solve the problem. See [ask] for more on the types of things we expect to be in questions.

Comment: I updated your code formatting so that it is easier to read.  Can you please re-run this format and update the error message so that the line numbers match? By breaking your code into multiple lines it is not only easier to read but easier to debug.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy admittedly I am still learning. Since you posted that this question needed rewriting, I wanted to ask you if it makes sense now.  At first I was not able to make sense of what the OP wanted.  Then after several edits to the format and layout I was able to read it and even answer it.  My question to you is this, does the question make sense now that it is better formatted or is there something else to do? I ask for my own learning on writing better questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you forgot a `WHERE` clause on your `UPDATE` statement.  Was this intentional?

Maybe something like:

```
WHERE TRIM(DDY.INV_NUM) = TRIM(RUR1.INV_NUM);
```